# How to avoid Elastic IP translation to private IP when setting Cassandra listen_address for external client connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, cassandra, ip

I am setting

listen_address: private IP (gets translated by AWS to public IP, whether I ask it to or not)
broadcast_address: public IP
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

I'm not able to do this because of that automatic NAT'ing stuff being done by AWS Elastic IP.  Cassandra refuses to start, claiming that I need to specify an address that I can bind to (e.g. my private IP), and instead giving me the public, elastic IP as my 7000 port listen_address setting.
..but I did this.  And it translated to public anyway.

I tried dual-homing it, but I can't even talk to the private IP on the second NIC, so I'm kind of stuck.

Is there a workaround for this elastic IP translation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Client connections rely on `rpc_address`. You'll need to set the following as a starting point:

```
listen_address: private_ip
rpc_address: public_ip
```

If nodes are distributed across regions and using `Ec2MultiRegionSnitch` set:

```
broadcast_address: public_ip
```

so nodes can communicate with nodes in another region. Cheers!